# "Pathfind" a linked list?

Tags: c#, list, simulation, path-finding

I'm toying with the idea of making a sort-of virtual network "simulator" if you will. I wanted to put together something of a linked-list (or best I can describe it as).

Imagine it like a normal IP network made of objects. Then passing messages along them between remotely-linked nodes. Even if I have to "cheat" to some degree by being able to know the path, and instead update all relevant nodes in the path that a message supposedly through it, without actually -moving- the message object -through- the nodes. I'd still need to know what nodes needed to be notified and thus still at the very least need to know the path.

So, it's not exactly a linked list. Or maybe I don't know the terms I need to convey the issue, but pointing me in the right direction, or of course some code examples, would be delightfully appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a [routing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing)..?

Comment: Yeah, seems that's what I need. I've been reading up in the meantime, and think that I need to be using Dijkstra's algorithm.